# Change android theme runtime

Tags: android, themes, runtime

I have backend response with some bunch of colors that I need to change in my app. Is there any way to change theme attributes for activity? I understand that I can change whole theme but I don't know what colors will be used in future. So my app has to be customizable totally from the backend

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`setTheme()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTheme(int)) for an activity before calling `setContentView()`. The theme will be changed just for that activity.

If you want totally customized colors (that can't be captured in a set of pre-defined themes) then you're going to have to set up your activity and its views to do that in code.